# How to get ID of cell in Jupyter kernel?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to build a Jupyter kernel for a language that doesn't really support a REPL, and re-defining a variable or function throws an error in that language. Unfortunately that means that I can't just keep executing the code in the order the user submits it, but instead need to substitute it if they re-visit an older cell. Let's say the user has the following two cells:

Cell 1:

```
int foo = 1;
```

Cell 2:

```
vec4(foo);
```

In my ideal scenario, I just want to stitch the cells together into one virtual source file that is in cell order and then execute that. So the resulting virtual source file should be this:

```
int foo = 1;
vec4(foo);
```

Now let's say the user goes back to cell 1 and edits foo to be 4, how can I find out that the user edited cell 1? So ideally I want to update the virtual source file to look like this:

```
int foo = 4;
vec4(foo);
```

Instead of this:

```
int foo = 1;
vec4(foo);
int foo = 4; // This would throw an error in the language compiler
```

I'm using [this](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrapperkernels.html) as my base and I've looked through the source but have been unable to find anything that would help me. Is there something that I missed? Anything else that I should be doing instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres goes a possible solution using messaging_api (https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html#history).

```py
import asyncio
import os
from uuid import uuid4
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass

from tornado.escape import json_encode, json_decode, url_escape
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient, HTTPRequest

client = AsyncHTTPClient()
session_id = 'faf69f76-6667-45d6-a38f-32460e5d7f24'
token = 'e9e267d0c802017c22bc31d276b675b4f5b3e0f180eb5c8b'
kernel_id = 'fad149a5-1f78-4827-ba7c-f1fde844f0b2'

@dataclass
class Cell:
    code: str
    index: int
    execution_count: int

# We keep track of all cells to matain an updated index
cells = []

async def get_sessions():
    url = 'http://localhost:8888/api/sessions?token={}'.format(token)
    req = HTTPRequest(url=url)
    resp = await client.fetch(req)
    print(resp)
    print(resp.body)

async def get_notebook_content(path):
    url = 'http://localhost:8888/api/contents/{}?token={}'.format(path, token)

    req = HTTPRequest(url=url)
    resp = await client.fetch(req)
    return json_decode(resp.body)

async def get_session(session_id):
    ses_url = 'http://localhost:8888/api/sessions/{}?token={}'.format(session_id, token)
    ses_req = HTTPRequest(url=ses_url)
    resp = await client.fetch(ses_req)
    return json_decode(resp.body)

# return the list of notebook cells as Cell @dataclass
def parse_cells(content):
    res = []
    # we iterate over notebook cells
    cells = content['content']['cells']
    # search the cell
    for index, c in enumerate(cells):
        cell_execution_count = c['execution_count']
        code = c['source']
        cell = Cell(code=code, index=index, execution_count=cell_execution_count)

        res.append(cell)

    return res

# listen to all notebook messages
async def listen():
    session_data = await get_session(session_id)
    notebook_path = session_data['notebook']['path']
    notebook_content = await get_notebook_content(notebook_path)

    # parse existing cells
    cells = parse_cells(notebook_content)

    # listen to all messages
    req = HTTPRequest(
        url='ws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/{}/channels?token={}'.format(
            kernel_id,
            token))
    ws = await websocket_connect(req)
    print('Connected to kernel websocket')
    hist_msg_id = None

    while True:
        msg = await ws.read_message()
        msg = json_decode(msg)
        msg_type = msg['msg_type']
        parent_msg_id = msg['parent_header']['msg_id']

        if msg_type == 'execute_input':
            # after a executed cell we request the history (only of the last executed cell)
            hist_msg_id = uuid4().hex
            ws.write_message(json_encode({
                'header': {
                    'username': '',
                    'version': '5.3',
                    'session': '',
                    'msg_id': hist_msg_id,
                    'msg_type': 'history_request'
                },
                'parent_header': {},
                'channel': 'shell',
                'content': {
                    'output': False,
                    'raw': True,
                    'hist_access_type': 'tail',
                    'n': 1
                },
                'metadata': {
                },
                'buffers': {}
            }))
        elif parent_msg_id == hist_msg_id and msg_type == 'history_reply':
            # we receive the history of the last executed cell with his execution_count
            hist_msg_id = None # we dont expect more replies
            # see message type 'history_result': https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html#history
            execution_count = msg['content']['history'][0][1]
            code = msg['content']['history'][0][2]
            # update the existing cell
            for c in cells:
                if c.execution_count + 1 == execution_count:
                    c.code = code
                    c.execution_count = execution_count

                    print('# Cell changed: {}'.format(c))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(listen())
```

Let me try to explain it ...

- We keep track of all notebooks cells and his index on a list (cells) of a Cell dataclass (code, index and execution_count)
- We listen for each message from the desired session (method listen)
- When a cell get's executed we request his history through the message api, to get the code and execution_count
- We match the cell with the existing one throigh his execution_count and update it

I know it's a very peculiar solution, but when the notebook comunicates with the messages api, doesn't include any information about some sort of cell identity, only his code.

**Important note**

This solution does not manage inserting or deleting cells, we would have to find a solution using the kernel history or something like that ...